# Submit form only if all required fields are full?

Tags: javascript

I want to do form.submit() but only if all form items with the required attribute are full.

I was thinking on simpy iterating through the form children in search for the attribute, but I'm not sure how to do it since there might be nested elements and such. And probably there is an easier way to do it.

```
this.form_is_full = function(form){
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
        if(form.elements[i].getAttribute("required") && form.elements[i].value=="")
        {
        // If has attribute required and is blank return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
this.validate_form = function(form){
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
        if(form.elements[i].value == "" && form.elements[i].getAttribute("name") && form.elements[i].hasAttribute("required"))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Validate()
        {


        // create array containing textbox elements
        //for example:
        var inputs = [document.getElementById('fname'), 
        document.getElementById('lname'), document.getElementById('email'), 
        document.getElementById('messagetxt')];

        var error;

        for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
        // loop through each element to see if value is empty
        {
            if(inputs[i].value == '')
            {
                error = 'Please complete all fields.';
                alert(error);
                return false;
                }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#YourFormId').submit(function(e) {
    if ($.trim($("#YourFormId input").val()) === "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('you did not fill out one of the fields');
    }
});
```